# Angular AoT Generates Incorrect External Directory References

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, angular-aot

I've been working on creating a project (all Typescript) that contains multiple Angular and NodeJS projects. That part is going pretty well, but I figured it would be pretty great if I could have a library folder under my source folder that all of my Typescript project could share project modules with, Typescript interfaces, NgModules, etc. However, when I compile the source for production, the ModuleFactory references to the actual models do not translate correctly for my 'lib' NgModules.

I have created a demo and uploaded it to my GitHub as an example:
https://github.com/ItsBaneDude/broken-external-links

I've included the compilation scripts as npm scripts under

```
npm run build-aot  // Builds and fails for production
npm run build-jit  // Builds and runs for dev i.e. "ng serve --dev"
npm run compile-aot // To compile and keep AoT folder in src, just ngc
```

I forgot to put the JiT serve script so you could automatically see it running it in the browser, but I mean you can just do `ng serve --dev` to achieve that.

So, what happens: you try to build for production, `npm run build-aot`, it says

```
ERROR in C:/Users/Bane/Documents/node_projects/broken-external-libs/src/project-ng/aot/lib/modules/test/test.module.ngfactory.ts (10,21): Cannot find module './test.module'.
```

Bummer. I wonder why.

*Runs AoT compile with* `npm run compile-aot`*... It "works"...*

Okay, so the AoT foder gets generated at `src/project-ng/aot`. If I go into `.../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts`, I see on line 10 an **import** statement for my app module.

`import * as i1 from '../../app/app.module';`

Okay, cool, it follows correctly all the way back to `../../app/app.module` and resolves successfully.

However, if I go into the AoT folder again, except inside my `lib` folder, to `...aot/lib/modules/test/test.module.ngfactory.ts`, I see it on line 10, again, trying to **import** my TestModule, but from `./test.module`

`import * as i1 from './test.module';`

But, as we know as rational, self-and-computer-aware human-beings, it should be more like `../../../../../lib/modules/test/test.module`.

**y tho**

To be completely fair I've only recently started Angular development, so if some of this seems hazy to me, it might be because I suck. But I'm looking to suck less! If anyone would care to lend me a hand, I would be very appreciative of your borrowed expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I ended up discovering and going with was:

Angular Compiler-CLI < 1.5.0-rc.5 (I think it's release candidate 5, I didn't look through the change logs) does not support this behavior. At the very beginning of this project with months to develop the code ahead, I'm just developing in Angular 5 and getting the results I expected.